# What is the part of speech of "to talk" in this sentence?

Tags: parts-of-speech, infinitives

I was trying to understand how to translate this sentence into another language, and I realized I do not fully understand it in English!

The sentence is:

> We chose to meet up to talk about the plans.

What I was able to figure out:

- *We* is the sentence, *chose* is the main verb.
- *to meet up*: I *think* this is one verb in the infinitive acting as the direct object.
- *to talk*: Not sure! some kind of infinitive?
- *about the plans* prep phrase modifying the talk. (I guess this is adjectival if *to talk* is an infinitive?)

Comment: It means this: We chose to meet up *in order to* talk about the plans.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinitive modifier subject or object or depends on context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238382/infinitive-modifier-subject-or-object-or-depends-on-context) ( ... I gave her medicine to prevent her becoming sick again. [Marius Hancu] ...
The infinitive [here is] called an infinitive of purpose and has the meaning of "in order to do".)

Comment: Voting to reopen because the purported duplicate is quite clearly unrelated; that question is about the understood subjects of these infinitives, not about their roles in the clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's an infinitive. More specifically, "to talk about the plans" is an infinitival clause serving as a purpose adjunct ([Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), p. 728); some grammars would say that it's "acting adverbially."

It's worth noting that, if you believe Huddleston & Pullum, "to talk" doesn't form a syntactic unit. In other words, the structure of this is not "[to talk] about the plans" but "to [talk about the plans]," with the word *to* functioning as a subordinator for the verb phrase "talk about the plans." This explains the structure of sentences like "I need to go home but I don't want to," where the subordinate verb phrase is ellipted, and "I need to leave and go home," where the two verb phrases "leave" and "go home" are joined together, both being subordinated by the *to*  (*ibid.,* p. 1183-1184).

Comment: Yes, to [talk about the plans]. My only disagreement is that I don't see "to" as a *subordinator* but as setting up a relationship between what's to the left and to the right. This is like:  He likes **to** take time off and ski. *to* as a function word merely puts those in proximity, sets up a relationship between them. Unfortunately, the linguist who came up with this is French and little of his work on English has been translated into English.